# multi instance / multi tab method

Tags: c#

I need some abstract method which will handle multiple controls like `ListView`.

Now I have something like this. I need write every panel in function for panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4 etc:

```
private void ListDir(string path, int panel_number)
{
  foreach (string dir in ListDirectories(@path))
            {
                ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(dir);
                switch (panel_number)
                {
                   case 1:
                          panel1.Items.Add(li);
                          break;
                   case 2:
                          panel2.Items.Add(li);
                          break;
                   case 2:
                          panel3.Items.Add(li);
                          break;
            }
}
```

But I need to make this function more abstract I need it for multiple tabs with same controls like this. User can create x numbers of new tabs and I can't handle it in switch case.

Just to be clear my goal is:

```
private void ListDir(string path, int panel_number)
{
  foreach (string dir in ListDirectories(@path))
            {
                ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(dir);
                panel[panel_number].Items.Add(li); 
            }
}
```

Comment: Use a list of Panels. `List<Panel>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code section of your post will work if only you create a member field with a list of Panels like this:

```
private List<Panel> panel = new List<Panel>();
```

When your panels have been created (for example in onLoad add them to the panel list

```
panel.AddRange(new Panel[]{ panel1, panel2, panel3 });
```

Note that `panel_number` now will have to be zero-indexed, meaning calling `ListDir(path, 0)` will add it to `panel1`.